# Как изменть MAC у bluetooth HM-05?

Tags: сеть, arduino, bluetooth

Всем привет, недавно приобрел у китайских друзей два BLE модуля, конкретно какой модели выяснить так и не удалось, думаю что HM-05, прошивка - "+VERSION=Firmware V4.2.0,Bluetooth V4.0 LE".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но вот незадача, у них один и тот же MAC адрес, что исключает их подключение к одному мастеру.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить МАС на одном из модулей? Нагуглить не удалось(((

Comment: А его можно по usb подключить? Если я не ошибаюсь, то через bluetoothctl это можно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через AT команды нельзя, даже даташит об этом пишет...
https://lib.chipdip.ru/164/DOC001164956.pdf

есть вариант перепрошить модуль(лучше спросить у китайцев как), потому что нашел в сети как прошивают, но довольно геморно:
https://radiokot.ru/circuit/digital/pcmod/39/
там как раз таки меняют адрес устройства

Удачи:)